# How come when I create a class derived from another GameComponent class, the game class will only update what's in the original class' update?

Tags: c#, class, xna, updating, derived

When I am creating my class `ConfigsPC` which is derived from another class which I created as a base class, `Configs`, I am not able to update anything in the `Update` method for the class `ConfigsPC` but I am able to update stuff in the `Update` method for the class `Configs`. This is my problem, I don't know what is wrong with the way I am approaching this type of situation, am I not able to do what I am trying to do? If I am, what is a possible way of fixing this issue?

```
public class ConfigsPC : Configs
{
    public ConfigsPC(Game game)
        : base(game)
    {
        this.Initialize();
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Example of a value I'm trying to update.
        Game.IsMouseVisible = false;
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}

public class Configs : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameComponent
{
    public Configs(Game game)
        : base(game)
    {
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to add some code - as little as possible while being complete

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to make your `Update` method [`virtual`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding#C.23). But without seeing your code it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: @Jake now we tackle "I am not able to update anything in the Update method for the class ConfigsPC" What stops you compile error? what does it say?

Comment: @Jake if this is the exact code you are using, is it possible that  the `IsMouseVisible ` field is getting reset within `base.Update(gameTime);`

Comment: @Jake I suggest stepping through with debugger

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to register `ConfigsPC` with your game's components collection?

```
public class ConfigsPC : Configs
{
    public ConfigsPC(Game game)
        : base(game)
    {
        this.Initialize();
        game.Components.Add(this); // add this line
    }
```

It will only automatically call update on components that are added to the collection.